# Calling a method inside a method of a different class C++

Tags: c++, class

In my code, I have two classes. The first class has a private variable x. I'm trying to change its value by calling a method defined in a second class - `setClass1X()`. This method takes two parameters, the value that I want to set x to and an object of type class1. This method should call another method `setX()` of an object given as a parameter and pass it the value that i want to set x to. Then that method `setX()`, defined in the first class should set the value of x for that particular object. At the end program calls a function `getX()` from the first class and prints its return value. I always get 0 as an output because that is what constructor sets the value of x to, meaning that this approach does not work. Can you spot a mistake or tell my why this approach does not work. Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class class1
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    class1()
    {
        x=0;
    }
    int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    void setX(int a)
    {
        x=a;
    }
};

class class2
{
public: 
    void setClass1X(int n, class1 c)
    {
        c.setX(n);
    }
};



int main()
{   
    class1 c1;
    class2 c2;
    c2.setClass1X(5, c1);
    cout << c1.getX();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeCAT has already pointed out **a copy of class1 being pass and the changes made to the copy doesnt reflect into the original instance**. So the solution is to pass the instance by reference.

However classes should be dependned on each other at the class level rather than at method level to mark clear dependnecy; unless you there is specific reason for not doing this.

```
class class2
{
private:
    class1& c1;
public: 
    class2(class1& c)
       : c1(c)
    {
    }

    void setClass1X(int n)
    {
        c1.setX(n);
    }
};

int main()
{   
    class1 c1;
    class2 c2(c1);
    c2.setClass1X(5);
    cout << c1.getX();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your `setClass1X` function, a **copy of** an object is passed to `c1`, so modification to that won't affect caller.

To have your functions modify what is passed, you should use references.

```
void setClass1X(int n, class1& c) // add "&"
{
    c.setX(n);
}
```